# plusone.js sometimes is "pending" on chrome?

Tags: google-plus

Using Chrome (22.0....), sometimes, when I try to take :

```
<script src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it fails. I mean, if I check the Network console, it says "Pending...", and my .load() events are stuck.

Why? And how can I fix it?

Also tried with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

but it is the same...

Comment: Is there a location this is hosted to take a look at it ourselves? The code itself looks fine, but something else might be happening.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the HTML container for the +1 button defined anywhere in the source of the page that you linked. I see the first script that you referenced on the page, but your page appears to be missing:

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300"></div>
```

The second snippet of script is intended for asynchronous loading (preferred) that you reference also would require you to insert the same type HTML container.

You can generate the code to include in your page using the [+1 button configuration tool](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/).

[UPDATE]
The g-plusone element apparently is being injected dynamically by jQuery, which has a different onload timing than the +1 button's own onload handler, which explains why sometimes it might display. In this case, you need to use the parseTags: explicit option:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {parsetags: 'explicit'}
</script>
```

And then after your own JavaScript injects the g-plusone div, you must call:

```
gapi.plusone.go();
```

Which will explicitly render all +1 buttons on the page when initiated.

Comment: Because I put it when the page is load, with jquery, before render it!

Comment: It is important that you provide all the relevant details when you're asking for support, including the website URL, the methods that you're trying.

I've edited my answer to deal with this new information.

Comment: Tried, but it still not render the plugins every time! The problem is not on rendering, but on "download" plusone.js...

Comment: I've tried a bunch of times and have never seen the plusone.js file fail to download for your site.  I do see the +1 button load and display in both Firefox and Chrome, but not until the second photo loads. I think there is a timing issue for when you're calling the gapi.plusone.go() method. I also see a Javascript problem occurring with your Facebook scripts in the console, not sure that is related, but if it prevents the parent element from loading properly maybe it is the cause.